# How to disable unnecessary using directive check in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm writing a small application which compiles and executes C# code snippets using `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` (Roslyn). I get the code snippets as user input, so I do not know which namespaces will be required for the code to compile. The basic concept now is that I always include the `System` namespace. But if the code snippet does not use it, I get `Unnecessary using directive exception`.

Is there a way to disable this check?

I already experimented with `CSharpCompilationOptions`. Setting `warningLevel` to `0` did not solve the problem.

Edit: Sorry, you are right, it's not an exception, but an element of the array returned by GetDiagnostics(). So I can filter / ignore it. Thanks.

Comment: That shouldn't be an exception.  What's the stack trace?

Comment: Could you include a short sample code that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either just filter out `Diagnostic`s with `Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Info`, or else pass a nowarn configuration option for that specific error code.

Comment: how do pass a nowarn configuration option for that

Comment: `NoWarn` only work on warnings. These have a default severity of `Hidden` and I don't think you can get rid of them.